# Insert of getdate()-1 into table field with type date throws error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, date

This is a strange issue as i have run this simple t-sql many times but now it is throwing error.

I am doing a simple insert of yesterday date with a cast of getdate()-1 as date.  Now it is giving error that cannot convert string. How can i properly show yesterday date as date format to insert into this table:

Full code:

```
select VariantID, OH_QTY, cast( GETDATE()-1 as date) WeekEndDate, 
case when COMPAREATPRICE IS NULL THEN 'FP' 
WHEN Price<CompareAtPrice then 'MD' else 'FP' end as PRICE_TYPE
from D_PRODUCTS
where OH_QTY is not null and OH_QTY <> 0
```

Table Structure:

```
    [VariantID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OH_QTY] [int] NULL,
    [PRICE_TYPE] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [WeekEndDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).  (2) Show the full text of the error.  If you are doing an `insert`, you have not shown the full code.  Also, it is unclear if you have one table or two tables involved i n your real query.  And, you have columns that are not shown in the table definition.

Comment: You are selecting WeekEndDate then PRICE_TYPE, while your table seems to have them in opposite order. An insert statement uses position, not name

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, which -- if I had to speculate -- is due to an `insert` where you don't list the columns.

However, you can simplify this snippet of code by taking advantage of the fact that `NULL` values fail most comparisons:

```
select VariantID, OH_QTY,
       dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) as WeekEndDate, 
       (case when Price < CompareAtPrice then 'MD' else 'FP' end) as price_type
from D_PRODUCTS
where OH_QTY <> 0;
```

Note that I prefer an explicit `dateadd()` to `getdate() - 1`, although your version is technically fine.

You can run this query *stand-alone* and you should see that it works.  The only possible type conversion problems would be some of `Price`, `CompareAtPrice` or `OH_QTY` were strings -- but it would be silly to store prices as strings.

If this works stand-alone, then the issue is with the `insert`, which you haven't included in the question.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  My original code was cut off it was   insert into F_WEEKLY_INVENTORY
select VariantID, OH_QTY, cast( GETDATE()-1 as date) WeekEndDate, 
case when COMPAREATPRICE IS NULL THEN 'FP' 
WHEN Price<CompareAtPrice then 'MD' else 'FP' end as PRICE_TYPE
from D_PRODUCTS
where OH_QTY is not null and OH_QTY <> 0

Comment: the select portion of which works fine, but the insert fails.  I tried replacing with your date add version and it fails with same error.  What am I doing wrong? I did notice you are correct compareatprice is stored as a varchar format  which makes more sense on the error!

Comment: However I tried to create a new products table updating compare at price to numeric(28, 6) same as the price field and then run the insert and it still failed.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was dumb on my part, I had the fields being inserted in the wrong order.  Thank you for steering me in the right direction!